Laravel Vue Inertia How to accept data from a checkbox and store it in the database?
It will read from the database and put an appropriate check in the checkbox (or leave it blank), but I can't get it to update the database when the user checks a checkbox. The other fields work, they update to the database.
<template>
    <form>
      <div>
        <div @input="update">
          <input v-model="form.month" type="text" />
          <input v-model="form.day_deposited" type="text" />
          <input v-model="form.description" type="text" />
          <input v-model="form.amount" type="text" />
          <input v-model="form.paid" type="checkbox" true-value="1" false-value="0" />
          <Link :href="`/income/${props.income.id}`" method="DELETE" as="button" preserve-scroll>Delete</Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
</template>
 
  <script setup>
  import { useForm } from '@inertiajs/vue3'
  import { Link } from '@inertiajs/vue3'
  const props = defineProps({
    income: Object
  })

  const form = useForm({
    id: props.income.id,
    month: props.income.month,
    day_deposited: props.income.day_deposited,
    description: props.income.description,
    amount: props.income.amount,
    paid: props.income.paid,
  })

  const update = () => form.put(`/income/${props.income.id}`, {preserveScroll:true})
  </script>


Have you checked your HTTP request payload to see what value is being sent to the server?

Test with postman first? Verify that the route is being properly handled? Or utilize burp suite to intercept what exactly is even being sent to the server. We need more information before we can help you debug here.

If the checkbox is empty and I check it, this is the payload:
{id: 2, month: null, day_deposited: "2", description: "Cole and Sons", amount: "2934", paid: 0}
amount
:
"2934"
day_deposited
:
"2"
description
:
"Cole and Sons"
id
:
2
month
:
null
paid
:
0
If I uncheck it, this is the payload:
{id: 2, month: null, day_deposited: "2", description: "Cole and Sons", amount: "2934", paid: "1"}
amount
:
"2934"
day_deposited
:
"2"
description
:
"Cole and Sons"
id
:
2
month
:
null
paid
:
"1"
"1" for unchecked and "0" for checked.

@MarianneHartigan that will be due to your true-value and false-value attributes. You can work with 1 and 0 though, so this is likely a backend issue. What does your controller look like? Are you updating a database record via its model? If so, have you added paid to the $protected properties array? Have you casted the property to a boolean? Is your database column setup correctly? We need more information to help you.
